# How can we replace/remove element if data is blank

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, swift3

I have a view controller, where I have a UIImage and UIlabels. This UIimage - image loads from the server and and the UIlabel text gets the value from the fields defined in the database. Now, in some records we dont have Images on the server and are blank, but there will be always the UILabel values. So if we dont have image value, how can we remove the UIImage and bring the labels up (as seen in the screenshots).

In the first screenshot we have the image so thats fine but the second screenshot we only have text and want to bring the text up. Is there a easy way?

Also, if we have various size image in regards to height and width, so how can we get the actual size of the image loaded on the app from the server

### First Screenshot

[image: FirstImage.png]

### Second Screenshot

[image: Second Screenshot]

code:

```
   private func checkImage(_ imageString:String)
{
    self.imageUI.layoutIfNeeded()
    if imageString.characters.count >= 2
    {
        if imageString != "<null>"
        {
            let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.xyz.com.au/images/"+imageString)

            let data = NSData(contentsOf:url! as URL)
            if data != nil
            {
                imageUI.image = UIImage(data:data! as Data) //= UIImage(data:data!)
                //imageUI.sizeToFit()



                let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as! URL)
                let Image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)!

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if data != nil
                {
                    // We've received valid image.
                    // Find the height & Width of received image and update the image-view's height constraint.
                     imageUI.image = data!.size.height

                }
                else
                {
                    // Sorry,The received image is invalid,Need to hide Image View,So make the Image-view height constraint's constant to 0 which eventually hides it self and pulls that below label up!
                    imageUI.constraints = 0
                }
            }

            }

        }
        else
        {
            //logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "error-404")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //logoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "error-404")
    }
}
```

[image: error image:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    // 1. Get a reference to your image view's height constraint from story board to View controller.
    // Assume "constraintImageViewHeight" is the object name of the IBOutlet of image view's height constraint.

    // 2. In Web service completion block,Check for received image is nil/null
    // Assume "imgRecieved" is the object name of UIImage converted from response received.

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if imgRecieved != nil
        {
            // We've received valid image.
            // Find the height & Width of received image and update the image-view's height constraint.
            constraintImageViewHeight.constant = imgRecieved!.size.height
        }
        else
        {
            // Sorry,The received image is invalid,Need to hide Image View,So make the Image-view height constraint's constant to 0 which eventually hides it self and pulls that below label up!
            constraintImageViewHeight.constant = 0
        }
    }
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620016/how-to-change-or-update-nslayoutconstraint-programmatically) out for more information.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Where you are getting confused and could you please tell me what all the errors you are getting?

Comment: I have posted my code in my Query. I have replaced the words instead of **constraintImageViewHeight**  my  object name is  **imageUI** and instead of ** imgRecieved** my  name for the object is  **data**

Comment: again, I am not getting the properties for UIimage (constant)  as defined by you in the code solution

Comment: First of all,replacing 
imageUI.image = data!.size.height With
imageUI.image = Image!.size.height
Will solve your 1st error,

Next,What is the height constraint name of Image-view?

Comment: Still having errors after replacing the code as suggested. This time the error is **cannot assign value of type GCFloat to type 'UIImage'**

Comment: and how do i find the height constraints? I have done any constraints for the Image-View

Comment: Please clarify me a couple of things,Firstly,
1. Have you given height constraint for your image view in storyboard?
2. If Yes,Have you taken reference(IBOutLet) to the height constraint in to your view controller?
3. If Yes,What's the name of Your height constraint reference in view controller?
So that i can help you further.

Comment: Check how to take reference of a UI Object's constraint to view controller from below Thread's first answer with 30 up votes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086054/unable-to-make-outlet-connection-to-a-constraint-in-ib

Comment: Thanks @Naresh, your code exec without any errors, however, if the image NIL, the text under (Data from database) does not goes to the top.

Comment: Have you given top spacing constraint from label to Image view?

Comment: Hi Naresh.  I am new to this Swift 3 and not too sure how to use the tools efficiently. What if, I email you my code and could you help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130456/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-naresh-reddy-m).

Answer (score 1):

You can just give it height constraint and set it to 0 (required priority ,disable it first, enable again when needed) if the image/label is nil, remember to make other involved constraint lower priority

Comment: is there any good example so that I get a clear idea how to code and understand well ? Thank alot tho!! :)

Comment: You can check the answers in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364555/auto-layout-how-to-hide-1-view-in-a-view-with-3-equal-width-views/38364787#38364787), kinda similar i suppose

Comment: technically your image view has a size of 0 when it has no image. Your problem lies there. And if your image is always gonna be the same (and therefore is the reason why the height is hardcoded), then you might as well include the image in the bundle to avoid loading every time